YouTube API v3: setting contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating field not reflecting in YouTube UI
I'm creating videos using the Videos insert API, and the contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating field does not seem to be setting the property correctly.
Using the Java library, I'm doing
new Video()
  .setContentDetails(
    new VideoContentDetails()
      .setContentRating(new ContentRating().setYtRating("ytAgeRestricted"))
  );

but the "Age restriction" property is always set to "No" on these created videos. Is there something I should be doing differently?

Consider to post a ticket on Issue Tracker - probably, this is a bug with their API.
